# Open link in a selected cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, hyperlink

I have a formula to generate text representing a link. I copy the text to my explorer address and open that link.

I would like to double click the cell to open the link. The generated text is in column "M".

I recorded this.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

The rest does not record.

Essentially the steps are

1. copy selection
2. open windows explorer (or could use start>run)
3. paste into address bar
4. open (or enter)

#### screenshot of file - please see column M

[image: screenshot of file - please see column M]

Comment: You should post your code and things you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .In short, you'll need to show your code attempts to solve this and where it's not working to get the most help on this site. If you also post a screenshot of a sample of your sheet, that would help us help you more as well.

Comment: i have tried to record the macro but the vba coding only gets as far as making a copy.  but i know the  coding for that is wrong too as its selecting a specific cell.  please see below. sorry im not very good with vba codes.

[quote]Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Range("M5").Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub[/quote]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code in there. It will be easier to read the code in a proper formatted way, instead of posting it on comments

Comment: sorry about that.  updated first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the `HYPERLINK` function (following is an example)?

```
      A
1   www
2   google
3   com
4   =HYPERLINK("http://"&A1&"."&A2&"."&A3)
```

This generates the string as a clickable hyperlink.

EDIT*

From your example you can just put `=HYPERLINK(M2)` into column `N` if you don't want to change whats already in `M`.

Comment: i never knew that formula existed!  thank you.  i have just placed my formula into a hyper link formula to make that work.  that works a treat.  (i essentially wanted to cut out the manual work of copy and pasting).  i will update the first post to suit.

Comment: Glad it worked, please feel free to accept an answer if it helped.